# Where exactly is QuickTime Player on OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, quicktime

I bought a used MacBook Pro Retina Mid 2012 with Mountain Lion. I can't seem to find the QuickTime Player anywhere. There is no such app in Apps nor in Utilities. When I right-click a video icon, Open With doesn't offer QuickTime (even if it's a .smil file, which is more QuickTime specific, not to mention any other type). Simply, there is no such thing as QuickTime Player on my system. Is this possible or am I doing something wrong? How can I get it (the current one, not the legacy one)? Apple doesn't offer any download as far as I can see, the page claims I have one. Only, I don't :-(

Any advice? Thanx...

Comment: Lets try to find it using your Terminal "mdfind Quicktime Player"

Comment: If you did not find it then the previous (vicious) owner has removed it. It is a integrated part of the Mountain Lion OS.

Comment: Guess so... :-/ @Buscar웃, many results, is there a way to narrow a search?

Comment: There is a "QT player" in Applications, and there is a second one called "QT player 7" in utility folder.

Comment: Try download from here http://support.apple.com/kb/DL923?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US then see if it will upgrade ?

Answer (score 1):

QuickTime Player should be located directly in /Applications/, that's its default location. QuickTime Player X is part of the OS installation, and Apple provides no separate downloads of the app.

Reinstalling the OS is of course a huge step just to get QuickTime back. If you have access to the Mountain Lion installer, you can use an app like [Pacifist](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/6812/pacifist) to extract QuickTime Player from it.

Mountain Lion, as it was a paid upgrade, also cannot simply be downloaded. You may have a copy of the installer on an usb drive or a dvd-r. Originally it was an App Store download, and when bought an app file called "Install OS X Mountain Lion" was placed in /Applications/. After the installation this file, which was more than 4 GB in size, was deleted. You can get it back from the Purchases tab in the App Store to re-download the file. If it shows as "Installed," you should try holding down the option key while clicking on the Purchases tab. You might also be able to locate the installer on a Time Machine backup in the /Applications/ folder.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for such a detailed answer. It's not in Applications nor do I see it in Purchases (it's possible that this computer was originally bought with ML on it). However I have Mavericks installed on an external drive, I'll try and extract it from there. At any rate, when I upgrade to Mavericks or Yosemite, I'll have it again, right?

Comment: Yes, upgrading the OS should give you QuickTime Player, as it's part of the OS.